# awk with if statements

Tags: shell, scripting, awk

I am trying to print from a file using awk, but my output is empty. 
Here is my code so far

```
accountNum=$1
while read -r LINE || [[ -n $LINE ]] ; do
            awk -F',' '{ if($1==accountNum) { print $3.$2 } }' Accounts
done < Accounts
```

I have also tried this:

```
accountNum=$1
while read -r LINE || [[ -n $LINE ]] ; do
            echo $LINE  | awk -F',' '{ if($1==accountNum) { print $3.$2 } }' 
done < Accounts
```

The input file is :

```
1,Doe,John
2,Rooney,Wayne
3,Smith,Will
4,Crow,Russel
5,Cruise,Tom
```

The expected output when I run the file is

```
$./file.sh 3
Will Smith
```

But I get the following

```
$./file.sh 3
$
```

That is nothing is being printed out. I know the solution with cut, but I want to use awk.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `-v` option of `awk`:

```
awk -F',' -v accNum="$1" '$1 == accNum {print $3,$2}'
```

With `$1` in double quote, the shell will handle all its special character ( if has ) for you.

Answer (score 3):

You have:

```
accountNum=$1
awk -F',' '{ if($1==accountNum) { print $3.$2 } }' Accounts
```

How does the shell variable `accountNum` get into `awk`? It doesn't: you need to provide its value to `awk` explicitly. You can use:

```
awk -F',' '{ if($1=='"$accountNum"') { print $3.$2 } }' Accounts
```

which leaves single quotes and has the shell substitute the value of its variable into the `awk` command, then reenters single quotes for the rest of the command string.

A better or at least more idiomatic script would be:

```
#!/bin/sh
accountNum=$1
awk -F, '$1 == "'"$accountNum"'" { print $3,$2 }' Accounts
```

which deals with non-numeric account numbers (quoting the substituted variable), uses a pattern block instead of an explicit `if` (the `{}` block will run if the test before it is true), and prints a space between the names as you wanted (because of `,`). If you prefer to use `if` explicitly, move the test inside your existing `if` statement.

Depending on your real goal `awk` may not be the best fit for what you're doing. The above still fails if the script's `$1` has quotes in it. The shell loop you had wasn't doing anything useful, although it would have repeated the output many times.

Comment: are you saying I should remove the `while` loop? :)

Comment: At least for the examples it isn't doing anything to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Your script already practically does the job without any `awk` at all:

```
while IFS=, read -r num last first
    do  [ $((num==accountNum)) -eq 1 ] && 
        printf '%s.%s\n' "$first" "$last"
done < Accounts
```

I'm not suggesting that this is a better or more efficient solution than using `awk` alone, but if you want the `while...read` loop, this certainly beats separate `awk` processes per each line. Just an FYI, I guess.

Comment: Not just one awk for every line, but that awk reads the entire file again for every line that the shell itself reads. Way to get a O(n^2) algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -v a="$1" -F ',' '$1 == a { print $3, $2 }' Accounts
```

With `-v a="$1"` we set the `awk` variable `a` to the value of the script's first command line argument, then we specify that the input is comma separated with `-F ','`.  If the first column is equal to the value of `a`, print the two other columns in reverse order.

You get nothing in your output as you are comparing the first column to the `awk` variable `accountNum`, which is unset.

Had there been an entry whose first column had 0 (zero) in it, that entry would have been printed.  This is because the value of unset variables in `awk` evaluates to zero.