# Tail command inside a for loop

Tags: shell-script

I studied that

```
ls -dtr1 * | tail -5 | awk 'NR==2'
```

lists the second last folder created among the last 5 folders created.

I wanted to use it inside a for loop:
So i created a shell script `forLoopExample.sh`

```
for ii in $(seq 1 $1)
do
  f_name=`ls -dtr1 * | tail -$1 | awk 'NR==$ii'`
  
     # mkdir $f_name in some other location
     # and some other operations 

done
```

I expected if i do `sh forLoopExample.sh 3`
the loop runs three times and does the expected operation for all the three folders.
but `mkdir` is throwing error.
[image]

Kindly help me in solving the error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the picture show?

Comment: The shell doesn't substitute variables in single-quotes, so the `$ii` in the `awk` command isn't doing what you want. You could use double-quotes instead, but it's really better to use awk's `-v` option to copy the shell variable into an awk variable (see [this Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145623/awk-with-if-statements/145637#145637)). BTW, I also recommend using [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) to check your script for other common mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three issues with your code:

1. You try to use a shell variable inside an `awk` program.  The correct way to do that is to make an `awk` variable with the value of the shell variable:

   ```
    awk -v line="$ii" 'NR == line'
   ```
2. You use C-like `/* ... */` comments in a shell script.  Comments in shell scripts are introduced with `#` and stretches to the next newline character.
3. You rely on parsing `ls` to get names in timestamp order.  This would break if a name contained a newline character.  Instead, use something like

   ```
    f_name=$( zsh -c 'print -rC1 *(/om[$1])' zsh "$ii" )
   ```

This uses the `zsh` shell to get the `ii`:th most recently modified directory name in the current directory. Note that the `mtime` timestamp on a directory is updated when a directory entry is added or deleted in the directory, not if an existing file is updated or if things are added to or removed from subdirectories.

In `zsh`, looping over the directories in the current directory in order of `mtime` timestamp:

```
for dir in *(/om); do
    # use "$dir" here
done
```

Use `*(/om[1,$1])` as the pattern to only loop over the first `$1` most recently modified directories.

See also:

- [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985)